# not able to append row when i give <tbody> tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table which loads data dynamically through jQuery. My code works fine if I remove the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags. Though when I add these tags the code will not work; specifically the rows will not append. The rows are adding under one column.

```js
if(responseJson.length!=null){
 $("#itemtable").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
   var table1 = $("#itemtable tbody");
   var i = 1;
   $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {
      var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
           rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['slno']);
           rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemname']); 
           rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemcode']); 
           rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['supplier']); 
           rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['receivedqty']); 
           rowNew.children().eq(5).text(value['rejectedqty']); 
           rowNew.children().eq(6).text(value['acceptedqty']); 
           rowNew.children().eq(7).text(value['remarks']); 
           rowNew.appendTo(table1);
           i++;
   });
}
```

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */
.t1 { border-collapse: collapse;  width: 100%;}
.t1 th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px;}
.t1 th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}
.t1 tbody { display: block; }
.t1 tbody {
    height: 300px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="0" id="itemtable" class="t1" border="1px"> 
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th> SLno</th>
        <th>Item name</th> 
        <th>Item code</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>  
        <th>Received qty</th>   
        <th>Accepted qty</th>   
        <th>Rejected qty</th>      
        <th>Remarks</th>             
    </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: it's quite strange that by making a simple example, if not declaring explicitly the `tbody`, the selecting `table tbody` would fail. Unless you have some existing rows added initially. Please try running a simple demo by yourself. I think your problem is something else. Try mocking a simple object to test (not involving with ajax request).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I understand you want your `tbody` to scroll, yes it does need to be a block, but you need to fix the layout of the `thead` and it's containing elements.  You can see the changes in the last two blocks of CSS.

Note: scrolling, fixed headers, and table layout (positioning and column widths) have long been a struggle to display visibly.  This is why, if you more accurate column width, you'll have to apply custom styles dynamically — a feat that is easier than it sounds.  You may instead not wish to re-create the wheel and explore a [DataTables](https://datatables.net).

```js
function rand() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1
}
var keys = [
  "slno",
  "itemname",
  "itemcode",
  "supplier",
  "receivedqty",
  "rejectedqty",
  "acceptedqty",
  "remarks"
];
var responseJson = [...Array(100)].map(r => {
  var r = rand(), o = {};
  keys.forEach(key=>{o[key]= [key,r].join('-');});
  return o;
});

if (responseJson.length != null) {
  var $tbl = $("#itemtable"),
    $tbody = $tbl.find('tbody');

  $tbody.find('tr').remove();

  $.each(responseJson, function(i, obj) {
    var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
      rowNew.children().eq(i).text(obj[key])
    });
    rowNew.appendTo($tbody);
  });
}
```

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */

.t1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.t1 th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.t1 th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.t1 tbody {
  display: block;
}

.t1 tbody {
  height: 8em;
  /* Just for the demo          */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}


/* ===== UPDATES HERE: ====*/

td {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* too much data affects visibility */
}

thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  /* fix width of table and columns */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="itemtable" class="t1" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>SLno</th>
      <th>Item name</th>
      <th>Item code</th>
      <th>Supplier</th>
      <th>Received qty</th>
      <th>Accepted qty</th>
      <th>Rejected qty</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: is it possible to convert mine to datatable as you said?

Comment: Just build the table and `$('table').DataTable()`; better yet, check out [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html)

Comment: I also reduced the height of the example above so you could better see the scrolling

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion. Seems like dataTable will simplify my work in very much better way. I just tired with adding class = " display" and requried jquery to map my table as dataTable. But it does not work. Could you please help me to get the required result

Comment: one more doubt , is it possible to map the user editable table as Datatable?

Comment: Of course, kavi.  You should select an answer to this question and then ask a new one about the DataTables.  Selecting an answer will boost your reputation.  Additionally, asking a new question will attract more people and you may gain more votes; again, boosting your reputation

Comment: Thank you! Will post new one

Answer (score 0):

Just uncomment the following from your styles..

```
.t1 tbody { display: block; }
```

This seems to be making the columns look as if they were under a single column..

Quick sample..

https://jsfiddle.net/juastyzL/

Comment: ah sorry.. didn't notice the scroll.. you're gonna have a heck of a time trying to get this to work in all browsers.. plugins are you friends!